# What is the type of horizontal line?

Tags: c++, qt

what is the type of horizontal line in Qt? I'm trying to add this widget onto another widget but I'm failing in finding what's the type of it.

Comment: separator?  is that what you are looking for?

Comment: You can create a simple [QFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html) and set its shape to `HLine`. Is that perhaps what you're looking for?

Comment: @smallB Great. Made it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you're looking for is simply a [QFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html). Using [setFrameShape()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#frameShape-prop) you can set its shape to [QFrame::HLine](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html#Shape-enum). That should achieve what you're looking for.